# Saving value of model field every month in Django

Tags: django, statistics

I need to save every month the value of a field of my model. I've seen Celery for scheduled tasks, but I was wondering if there is an other way to do it?

My code:

```
class Sales(models.Model):
    ...
    sales_objective = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
```

`sales_objective` can change from one month to an other, and I would like then to create some stats where I can show:

1. Sales objective for January: 123
2. Sales objective for February: 456
   etc...

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use celery you could write a script with python and call something like:

save_sale.py

```
python manage.py shell
sale = Sales()
...
sale.save()
```

Finally you could execute your sve_sale.py with `cron` on linux/mac